# Uninstall multiple android packages using adb

Tags: android, bash, shell, adb

I am trying to uninstall multiple packages using a bash script with adb uninstall.

In theory following scripts should work:

```
adb shell pm list packages com.your.app |
cut -d ':' -f 2 | while read line ; do
  adb uninstall --verbose $line
done
```

OR

```
adb shell pm list packages com.your.app |
cut -d ':' -f 2 |
xargs -L1 -t adb uninstall
```

I get the following error

> Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]

I also found that the problem is with adb commands not taking piped arguments or arguments from shell variables. For example the following command also

```
echo com.your.app | adb uninstall
```

This will also give the same error.

I have already looked at [delete packages of domain by adb shell pm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458909/delete-packages-of-domain-by-adb-shell-pm)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26872199/1778421

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\r is added added to the output from the first command. We can use `tr -d '\r'` to remove these characters.

```
adb shell pm list packages com.your.app |
cut -d ':' -f 2 |
tr -d '\r' |
xargs -L1 -t adb uninstall
```

Found the solution in [Echo outputting results in erratic order in BASH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229934)

Comment: The symbolic notation `'\r'` is not portable, though it should generally work with `tr` on Linux.  For a portable notation, try `'\015'`.